# Variable from imported module not recognised

Tags: python

Why is my program not recognising the `randNo` variable from the module `randnomodule` in the module `GuessLoop`?

Relevant code for `GuessLoop` module:

```
import sys
import random
import sys
import time
from randomnomodule import RandomNoGenerator

RandomNoGenerator(1, 21)

def GuessLoopFunc(guess):   

    print(randNo)
```

Code for `randnomodule` module:

```
import random

def RandomNoGenerator(lowerBound, upperBound):
    randNo = random.randrange(lowerBound, upperBound)
    return randNo
```

Error message I get:

...\GuessLoop.py", line 11, in GuessLoopFunc
print(randNo)
NameError: name 'randNo' is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `RandomNoGenerator(1, 21)`

You are only calling the function, but not saving its return value. Use this instead:

```py
randNo = RandomNoGenerator(1, 21)
```

Comment: That seems to have worked, thanks!

I thought that, since I return the answer of the function in the randomnomodule module to randNo, if I imported randomnomodule to another piece of code it would output randNo when I called the function...

Is this the proper way of handling code like I am doing?

Comment: @LuCS By writing `return randNo` in randnomodule you are not automatically defining `randNo` in GuessLoop module. You can obtain the value by calling the function and saving its return value into a variable.